# Splitting a date-range - can it be improved somehow?

Tags: java, datetime

I've created a method to split a date range into a collection of date-arrays. These arrays consist of two timestamps.

Example:

```
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("*****************************");
        System.out.println("Split 2.1.2004 to 26.3.2004: ");
        for (DateTime[] date : TimeSplitter.splitDateIntoMonths(new DateTime(2004, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0).toDate(),
                new DateTime(2004, 3, 26, 0, 0, 0, 0).toDate())) {

            System.out.println(date[0] + " and " + date[1]);

        }

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("*****************************");
        System.out.println("Split 1.1.2000 to 31.12.2005: ");
        for (DateTime[] date : TimeSplitter.splitDateIntoMonths(new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0).toDate(),
                new DateTime(2005, 12, 31, 0, 0, 0, 0).toDate())) {

            System.out.println(date[0] + " and " + date[1]);

        }
```

Results into:

```
*****************************
Split 2.1.2004 to 26.3.2004: 
2004-01-02T00:00:00.000+01:00 and 2004-01-31T00:00:00.000+01:00
2004-02-01T00:00:00.000+01:00 and 2004-02-29T00:00:00.000+01:00
2004-03-01T00:00:00.000+01:00 and 2004-03-26T00:00:00.000+01:00

*****************************
Split 1.1.2000 to 31.12.2005: 
2000-01-01T00:00:00.000+01:00 and 2000-01-31T00:00:00.000+01:00
2000-02-01T00:00:00.000+01:00 and 2000-02-29T00:00:00.000+01:00
2000-03-01T00:00:00.000+01:00 and 2000-03-31T00:00:00.000+02:00
2000-04-01T00:00:00.000+02:00 and 2000-04-30T00:00:00.000+02:00
2000-05-01T00:00:00.000+02:00 and 2000-05-31T00:00:00.000+02:00
2000-06-01T00:00:00.000+02:00 and 2000-06-30T00:00:00.000+02:00
2000-07-01T00:00:00.000+02:00 and 2000-07-31T00:00:00.000+02:00
2000-08-01T00:00:00.000+02:00 and 2000-08-31T00:00:00.000+02:00
2000-09-01T00:00:00.000+02:00 and 2000-09-30T00:00:00.000+02:00
2000-10-01T00:00:00.000+02:00 and 2000-10-31T00:00:00.000+01:00
2000-11-01T00:00:00.000+01:00 and 2000-11-30T00:00:00.000+01:00
2000-12-01T00:00:00.000+01:00 and 2000-12-31T00:00:00.000+01:00
2001-01-01T00:00:00.000+01:00 and 2001-01-31T00:00:00.000+01:00
2001-02-01T00:00:00.000+01:00 and 2001-02-28T00:00:00.000+01:00
2001-03-01T00:00:00.000+01:00 and 2001-03-31T00:00:00.000+02:00
2001-04-01T00:00:00.000+02:00 and 2001-04-30T00:00:00.000+02:00
2001-05-01T00:00:00.000+02:00 and 2001-05-31T00:00:00.000+02:00
2001-06-01T00:00:00.000+02:00 and 2001-06-30T00:00:00.000+02:00
2001-07-01T00:00:00.000+02:00 and 2001-07-31T00:00:00.000+02:00
2001-08-01T00:00:00.000+02:00 and 2001-08-31T00:00:00.000+02:00
2001-09-01T00:00:00.000+02:00 and 2001-09-30T00:00:00.000+02:00
2001-10-01T00:00:00.000+02:00 and 2001-10-31T00:00:00.000+01:00
2001-11-01T00:00:00.000+01:00 and 2001-11-30T00:00:00.000+01:00
2001-12-01T00:00:00.000+01:00 and 2001-12-31T00:00:00.000+01:00
2002-01-01T00:00:00.000+01:00 and 2002-01-31T00:00:00.000+01:00
2002-02-01T00:00:00.000+01:00 and 2002-02-28T00:00:00.000+01:00
2002-03-01T00:00:00.000+01:00 and 2002-03-31T00:00:00.000+01:00
2002-04-01T00:00:00.000+02:00 and 2002-04-30T00:00:00.000+02:00
2002-05-01T00:00:00.000+02:00 and 2002-05-31T00:00:00.000+02:00
2002-06-01T00:00:00.000+02:00 and 2002-06-30T00:00:00.000+02:00
2002-07-01T00:00:00.000+02:00 and 2002-07-31T00:00:00.000+02:00
2002-08-01T00:00:00.000+02:00 and 2002-08-31T00:00:00.000+02:00
2002-09-01T00:00:00.000+02:00 and 2002-09-30T00:00:00.000+02:00
2002-10-01T00:00:00.000+02:00 and 2002-10-31T00:00:00.000+01:00
2002-11-01T00:00:00.000+01:00 and 2002-11-30T00:00:00.000+01:00
2002-12-01T00:00:00.000+01:00 and 2002-12-31T00:00:00.000+01:00
2003-01-01T00:00:00.000+01:00 and 2003-01-31T00:00:00.000+01:00
2003-02-01T00:00:00.000+01:00 and 2003-02-28T00:00:00.000+01:00
2003-03-01T00:00:00.000+01:00 and 2003-03-31T00:00:00.000+02:00
2003-04-01T00:00:00.000+02:00 and 2003-04-30T00:00:00.000+02:00
2003-05-01T00:00:00.000+02:00 and 2003-05-31T00:00:00.000+02:00
2003-06-01T00:00:00.000+02:00 and 2003-06-30T00:00:00.000+02:00
2003-07-01T00:00:00.000+02:00 and 2003-07-31T00:00:00.000+02:00
2003-08-01T00:00:00.000+02:00 and 2003-08-31T00:00:00.000+02:00
2003-09-01T00:00:00.000+02:00 and 2003-09-30T00:00:00.000+02:00
2003-10-01T00:00:00.000+02:00 and 2003-10-31T00:00:00.000+01:00
2003-11-01T00:00:00.000+01:00 and 2003-11-30T00:00:00.000+01:00
2003-12-01T00:00:00.000+01:00 and 2003-12-31T00:00:00.000+01:00
2004-01-01T00:00:00.000+01:00 and 2004-01-31T00:00:00.000+01:00
2004-02-01T00:00:00.000+01:00 and 2004-02-29T00:00:00.000+01:00
2004-03-01T00:00:00.000+01:00 and 2004-03-31T00:00:00.000+02:00
2004-04-01T00:00:00.000+02:00 and 2004-04-30T00:00:00.000+02:00
2004-05-01T00:00:00.000+02:00 and 2004-05-31T00:00:00.000+02:00
2004-06-01T00:00:00.000+02:00 and 2004-06-30T00:00:00.000+02:00
2004-07-01T00:00:00.000+02:00 and 2004-07-31T00:00:00.000+02:00
2004-08-01T00:00:00.000+02:00 and 2004-08-31T00:00:00.000+02:00
2004-09-01T00:00:00.000+02:00 and 2004-09-30T00:00:00.000+02:00
2004-10-01T00:00:00.000+02:00 and 2004-10-31T00:00:00.000+02:00
2004-11-01T00:00:00.000+01:00 and 2004-11-30T00:00:00.000+01:00
2004-12-01T00:00:00.000+01:00 and 2004-12-31T00:00:00.000+01:00
2005-01-01T00:00:00.000+01:00 and 2005-01-31T00:00:00.000+01:00
2005-02-01T00:00:00.000+01:00 and 2005-02-28T00:00:00.000+01:00
2005-03-01T00:00:00.000+01:00 and 2005-03-31T00:00:00.000+02:00
2005-04-01T00:00:00.000+02:00 and 2005-04-30T00:00:00.000+02:00
2005-05-01T00:00:00.000+02:00 and 2005-05-31T00:00:00.000+02:00
2005-06-01T00:00:00.000+02:00 and 2005-06-30T00:00:00.000+02:00
2005-07-01T00:00:00.000+02:00 and 2005-07-31T00:00:00.000+02:00
2005-08-01T00:00:00.000+02:00 and 2005-08-31T00:00:00.000+02:00
2005-09-01T00:00:00.000+02:00 and 2005-09-30T00:00:00.000+02:00
2005-10-01T00:00:00.000+02:00 and 2005-10-31T00:00:00.000+01:00
2005-11-01T00:00:00.000+01:00 and 2005-11-30T00:00:00.000+01:00
2005-12-01T00:00:00.000+01:00 and 2005-12-31T00:00:00.000+01:00
```

The split-date-into-months method looks like this:

```
/**
 * Splits a date range into months. The method provides for each set the
 * start and the end date, so that specific days (1-3-2016 or 5-17-2016) can
 * be covered.
 * 
 * @param from
 *            The implied start-date
 * @param to
 *            The implied end-date
 * @return a collection whit the start and the end of each month laying
 *         between the two days. Also covering the months of the start- and
 *         the end-date itself.
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException
 *             Is thrown when the from-date is later than the to-date.
 */
static Collection<DateTime[]> splitDateIntoMonths(Date from, Date to) throws IllegalArgumentException {

    Collection<DateTime[]> dates = new ArrayList<DateTime[]>();

    DateTime dFrom = new DateTime(from);
    DateTime dTo = new DateTime(to);

    if (dFrom.compareTo(dTo) >= 0) {

        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Provide a to-date greater than the from-date");

    }

    while (dFrom.compareTo(dTo) < 0) {

        DateTime[] dar = new DateTime[2];
        dar[0] = dFrom;
        dar[1] = dFrom
                .withDayOfMonth(dFrom.getMonthOfYear() == dTo.getMonthOfYear() && dFrom.getYear() == dTo.getYear()
                        ? dTo.getDayOfMonth() : dFrom.dayOfMonth().getMaximumValue());

        dates.add(dar);

        dFrom = dFrom.plusMonths(1).withDayOfMonth(1);

    }

    return dates;

}
```

However, I feel like this could be improved somehow. Are there any major issues which can be improved?

*Note: I need to stick to Java 7*

*Note2: I use [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)*

Comment: Are you on Java 8?

Comment: @h.j.k. Nope ... sorry forgot to mention :) No lambda for you.

Comment: Is it Joda's DateTime?

Comment: @RobAu Yes, will add it to the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks pretty nice overall.

Small bits:

- I would create a special type for the `DateTime[]` (as it can have only exactly 2 `DateTime`s), or reuse an existing one. In joda's case `Interval`. 
  (If you use `Interval`, you can also provide a convienence static method that accepts an `Interval`)
- Use a access modifier (`public`) on your method
- Replace the `compareTo` with better readable `isBefore()` and `isAfter()` and `equals()` so the reader does not need to know the magic compare values.
- Your javadoc has an `mm-dd-YYYY` date format. Your example has `dd.mm.YYYY`.  I would stick to `YYYY-mm-dd`